# Using RandomAccessFile as an InputStream

Tags: java, types

I found some in-house Java code with a method defined to take an [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) object as argument:

```
public static double readDouble(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

Elsewhere, this method is called using a [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) object as an argument:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("/filepath/", "r");
Double value = readDouble(raf);
```

RandomAccessFile does not extend InputStream, and there is no wrapper or conversion at work.  Is this technically legitimate, or at least acceptable practice?  Is it likely to cause errors?

**Edit:** Problem resolved!  Much later in the class where readDouble() is defined, there's a method overload that takes RandomAccessFile as input:

```
public static double readDouble(RandomAccessFile f) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It can't be this way. There should be some other implementation of `readDouble` method. Check your static imports at usage class. If the code is really organized as you have described it should raise compilation errors.

Comment: Arrrg the method was overloaded, and I missed it.  There's a separate definition of readDouble() for RandomAccessFiles as input.  Thanks your help, @AlehMaksimovich!

Comment: Either of you should add an answer as the accepted answer.